# JS elements applying to the wrong image

Tags: javascript, html, button, background-image

I'm a beginner coder and a first time java user, I am attempting to change the background image of multiple different images on my webpage. Yet they are all applying to the same image.

```
<!--Store Items-->
<img id="merchitem1" src="Pictures/Final Images/ClearCrownT.png"/>
<!--black-->
    <div class="button">
    <!--<button onclick = "gfg_Run()"> 
        </button>-->
     <img src="Pictures/Final Images/Blackbutton.png" onclick = "gfg_Run()"/>
    </div>
<!--purple-->
    <div class="button1">
          <!--<button onclick = "gfg_Run1()"> </button>-->
          <img src="Pictures/Final Images/Purplebutton.png" onclick = "gfg_Run1()"/>
        </div>
<!--green-->
    <div class="button2">
        
    <img src="Pictures/Final Images/Greenbutton.png" onclick = "gfg_Run2()"/>   
    </div>
    <!--white-->
    <div class="button3">
    <img src="Pictures/Final Images/Whitebutton.png" onclick = "gfg_Run3()"/>   
    </div>
    <img id="merchitem1" src="Pictures/Final Images/ClearCrownT.png">

<!--store item 2-->
<img id="merchitem2" src="Pictures/Final Images/ClearCrownT.png">
<!--Black1-->
    <div class="button4">
    
     <img src="Pictures/Final Images/Blackbutton.png" onclick = "gfg_Run4()"/>
    </div>
<!--blue-->
    <div class="button5">
        
          <img src="Pictures/Final Images/Purplebutton.png" onclick = "gfg_Run5()"/>
        </div>
<!--green1-->
    <div class="button6">
        <!--<button onclick = "gfg_Run2()"></button>--> 
    <img src="Pictures/Final Images/Greenbutton.png" onclick = "gfg_Run6()"/>   
    </div>
    <!--white-->
    <div class="button7">
    <img src="Pictures/Final Images/Whitebutton.png" onclick = "gfg_Run7()"/>   
    </div>
        <script>
    var el_up = document.getElementById("GFG_UP");
        var el_down = document.getElementById("GFG_DOWN");
        var str = "Click on button to change the background color";
      //Button For Item 1 
      //color 1
        el_up.innerHTML = str;
      
        function changeImage(Image) {
            document.getElementById("merchitem1").style.backgroundImage = Image;
        }
          
        function gfg_Run() {
            changeImage("url('Pictures/Final Images/BlackT.png')");
            el_down.innerHTML = "Background Color changed";
             alert(document.getElementById("merchitem1").style.backgroundColor);
        }
        //color 2
        el_up.innerHTML = str;
      
        function changeImage(Image) {
            document.getElementById("merchitem1").style.backgroundImage = Image;
        }
          
        function gfg_Run1() {
            changeImage("url('Pictures/Final Images/PurpCrownT.png')");
            el_down.innerHTML = "Background Color changed";
             alert(document.getElementById("merchitem1").style.backgroundColor);
        } 
        //button 3
           el_up.innerHTML = str;
      
        function changeImage(Image) {
            document.getElementById("merchitem1").style.background = Image;
        }
          
        function gfg_Run2() {
            changeImage("url('Pictures/Final Images/GreenCrownT.png')");
            el_down.innerHTML = "Background Color changed";
             alert(document.getElementById("merchitem1").style.backgroundColor);
        }
        function buttonSize() { 
            
        }
        //button 3
           el_up.innerHTML = str;
      
        function changeImage(Image) {
            document.getElementById("merchitem1").style.background = Image;
        }
          
        function gfg_Run3() {
            changeImage("url('Pictures/Final Images/WhiteCrownT.png')");
            el_down.innerHTML = "Background Color changed";
             alert(document.getElementById("merchitem1").style.backgroundColor);
        }
        //Button For Item 2 
      //color 1
        //*el_up.innerHTML = str;
      
        function changeImage(Image) {
            document.getElementById("merchitem2").style.backgroundImage = Image;
        }
          
        function gfg_Run4() {
            changeImage("url('Pictures/Final Images/BlackT.png')");
            el_down.innerHTML = "Background Color changed";
             alert(document.getElementById("merchitem2").style.backgroundColor);
        }
        //color 2
        el_up.innerHTML = str;
      
        function changeImage(Image) {
            document.getElementById("merchitem2").style.backgroundImage = Image;
        }
          
        function gfg_Run5() {
            changeImage("url('Pictures/Final Images/PurpCrownT.png')");
            el_down.innerHTML = "Background Color changed";
             alert(document.getElementById("merchitem2").style.backgroundColor);
        } 
        //button 3
           el_up.innerHTML = str;
      
        function changeImage(Image) {
            document.getElementById("merchitem2").style.background = Image;
        }
          
        function gfg_Run6() {
            changeImage("url('Pictures/Final Images/GreenCrownT.png')");
            el_down.innerHTML = "Background Color changed";
             alert(document.getElementById("merchitem2").style.backgroundColor);
        }
        function buttonSize() { 
            
        }
        //button 4
           el_up.innerHTML = str;
      
        function changeImage(Image) {
            document.getElementById("merchitem2").style.background = Image;
        }
          
        function gfg_Run7() {
            changeImage("url('Pictures/Final Images/WhiteCrownT.png')");
            el_down.innerHTML = "Background Color changed";
             alert(document.getElementById("merchitem2").style.backgroundColor);
        }
```

I've tried changing the id names again and relinking them all and that didn't do anything. It comes up with the error "cannot set properties of null" Is there anyway I could fix this?

Comment: Every time you find yourself creating indexed variable names you know something went wrong. Functions can take arguments, use that feature. Also, there can be only a single variable (function in this case) with the same name, defining new variables with an existing name will just override the exisiting variable. Also, `id`s of the elements must be unique within the document, it's not possible to JS to make a difference between two elements with the same id, hence the first found element is always returned.

Answer (score -1):

One problem might be the path. Don't use space on your path. For example:
instead of using Pictures/Final Images/PurpCrownT.png, use Pictures/Final_Images/PurpCrownT.png